# normalize the input of relu function encountered a runtime error

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, autograd, relu

when I try to pass the maximum activation value from previous layer to normalize the input of relu in next layer I encounter a runtime error as below. However, when I pass fixed value it works well without any error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 175, in backward allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved
tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed
when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to
backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling
backward.
```

As you see in this code below, I pass the argument `prev_layer_max` from the previous layer and encounter the error:

```py
class th_norm_ReLU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, modify):
        super(th_norm_ReLU, self).__init__()
        self.therelu = F.relu
       

    def forward(self, input, prev_layer_max):
      output = input * (prev_layer_max / input.max())
      norm_output = self.therelu (output)
      
      return norm_output
```

But if I use a fixed value instead of passed `prev_layer_max` argument, as this code below I make it equal to `1` it works normally without any error:

```py
    def forward(self, input, prev_layer_max = 1):
        output = input * (1 / input.max())
        norm_output = self.therelu (output)
```

the training loop is as below :

```
for epoch in range(params.epochs):
    running_loss = 0

    start_time = time.time()
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        model.train()
        model.zero_grad()  
        optimizer.zero_grad()  
        labels.to(device)
        images = images.float().to(device)
        outputs = model(images, epoch)
        loss = criterion(outputs.cpu(), labels)  
        running_loss += loss.item()  
        loss.backward()  
        optimizer.step()
```

here is the forward in the model where I record the max of each layer in a list ( thresh_list ):

```
def forward(self, input, epoch):
    x = self.conv1(input)
    x = self.relu(x,1)
    self.thresh_list[0] = max(self.thresh_list[0], x.max()) #to get the max activation 
    x = self.conv_dropout(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.relu(x, self.thresh_list[0])
    self.thresh_list[1] = max(self.thresh_list[1], x.max())
    x = self.pool1(x)
    x = self.conv_dropout(x)
    x = self.conv3(x)
    x = self.relu(x, self.thresh_list[1] )
    self.thresh_list[2] = max(self.thresh_list[2], x.max())
```

The Relue function I call is :

```
self.relu = th_norm_ReLU(True)
```

and the_norm_ReLU model is shown above.

Comment: Can you show your training loop? You seem to have already called `backward` on `prev_layer_max` before this inference.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I have added the training loop and more explanation on my post, please check it.

Comment: I believe it would be best if you could provide a minimal example. Here it is not clear what your computation graph looks like and what `thresh_list` consists of.